# Pythonでディレクトリ配下にあるスクリプトの特定の関数を実行したい

Tags: python, python3

下記のようにスクリプトが配置されていて、main.pyからhogeフォルダ配下の複数（実際には複数になります。）のスクリプト内の、特定の関数を実行したいです。

```
/
├main.py
└hoge
  ├huga.py
  └piyo.py
```

huga.py

```
def execute():
  print('huga_execute')
```

piyo.py

```
def execute():
  print('piyo_execute')
```

上記の構成の場合に、main.pyからhuga.pyおよびpiyo.pyのexcute関数を実行したいということです。
勿論それぞれimportすれば実行できますが、そうではなく、動的に実行したいです。
（hoge配下のスクリプトは増減する可能性があり、main.pyを変更せずに対応したいため。）

main.py

```
import hoge.huga # importでhugaやpiyoは記載しない、
import hoge.piyo

hoge.huga.execute() # これらを実行したい
hoge.piyo.execute()
```

イメージとしては下記のような感じで、何らかの方法でmodule?の一覧を取得して、そこから固定の関数を実行できればと考えております。

```
list = getModule('hoge') # ['huga', 'piyo']
for m in list:
  m.execute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

私はこんな感じでimportlibで実現しました。
問題の意味を取り違えていたで、追記しました。

```
import os
import importlib

path = "./hoge"

files = os.listdir(path)
modlist = [f for f in files if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))]
print(modlist)

# ココにmodlistから拡張子を除去したり、.py以外を弾いたリストに加工する処理

for funcname in modlist:
    plugmod = importlib.import_module("hoge."+funcname)
    ret = plugmod.execute()
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ただ、hogeディレクトリの中にあるファイルが増減するのです。（huga2.py、piyo2.py...が増える可能性がある。）よって、記載頂いたコードで言うところのmodlistの中身を知りたいイメージです。分かりづらくて申し訳ありません。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。importlibの方が新しいモジュールのようですのでこちらを使用するのが良さそうです！

Answer (score 2):

`importlib` というのを使うと出来るそうです。

[python動的モジュールの読み込み](https://qiita.com/ajitama/items/2ab42e4c7354dcd79266)

[importlib --- The implementation of import](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/library/importlib.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。確認してみたところ、find_module, find_specなどで実現できそうなのはわかりました。が、サンプルなどがなく苦戦しております。。。

Comment: 探して上位に来たものを見て紹介したので、多分他にも色々と方法はあるのだと思います。

Answer (score 0):

sys.modulesとinspectを使用することで実現できましたので回答として投稿いたします。

main.py

```
import sys, inspect
for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules['hoge']):
    if inspect.ismodule(obj):
        obj.execute()
```

以下が参考になりましたので記載しておきます。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796180

ただ、これがベストかどうかは自信がありません。
また、色々試しましたが、importlibで実現はできませんでした。
kunifさんもコメントしていますが、多分やり方次第でできそうな気もします。こちらを使用してのやり方がありましたら、是非記載していただけると嬉しいです。